# Angular 9: SCSS Import from fonts.google.com does not work in a production mode

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, font-face

I am importing a font in Angular 9 app `style.scss` using the following syntax:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap');
```

This works when I run `ng serve`. However, the import does not seem to work when the Angular bundle is deployed in the production mode. The production bundle makes no attempt to load this font - there is no network request. Further there are no errors in the Chrome console.

I have locally installed fonts that *do* work - so I suspect this has something to do with third-party hosted fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Korolev;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('assets/fonts/korolev-medium-webfont.ttf');
}
```

Tracing down the error, it is related to something called `injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js`, from a Webpack [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/blob/master/src/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js). This seems to do the trick when `ng serve` is run in the development mode, as we can see a request initiated from the script that creates `<style>` in the head that loads the font. However, when run in the production mode either the mechanism to load fonts is different or it does not seem to kick in.

[image: network log entry]

- Should SCSS imports from third party work normally in Angular production mode?
- If `import` for third party fonts is not recommended, what is the preferred mechanism to use third party fonts in stylesheets?

Comment: Did you by any change find a solution to this ?  I'm experiencing the same behavior, where other people I asked to verify don't !

Comment: I did not find a proper solution. I just hardcoded font links to `index.html`.

Comment: That's what I also did.  At least it is not in my bundle anymore, which lowers the size, but I really don't get why it doesn't work on my pc...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I just resolved it now by digging into [this angular's issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10855#issuecomment-480959538) on their github :

> I actually had this issue because my @import statement pulling in the google font was not being rendered as the first line in my compiled css file. I recently upgraded my version of Angular. Not sure why this change happened, but I solved for my case by breaking my font imports into a scss partial file and imported THAT partial file before anything else. The result is that my font @imports are the first line of my styles.css.

TLDR;
`@import` statements have to be at the top of the compiled css file or they will be ignored.

To do so, I created a file **font.scss** which contains all my `@import` like this :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Satisfy&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Patrick+Hand&display=swap');
// [...]
```

And then you need to update your **angular.json** to load this file first :

```
...
"styles": [
    "src/assets/scss/fonts.scss",
    "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
...
```